# Using jquery check/uncheck SelectAll checkbox when all the checkboxes in the group are checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I need `SelectAll` checkbox should be checked when all the `li`'s in the group checkboxes are checked.

Here I am having two checkbox groups. I need optimized code. try to work two ID's combindly?

**Note**: If all `li`'s are checked/unchecked other group should not be affected and vice-versa.

Please have a look at [my work till now](http://jsfiddle.net/rkamlekar/awnxx4zL/)

```
    <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="one_select_all"/> Group ONE Selecct All</li>
            <li><input class="one_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 1</li>
            <li><input class="one_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 2</li>
            <li><input class="one_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 3</li>
            <li><input class="one_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 4</li>
            <li><input class="one_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 5</li>
            <li><input class="one_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="two_select_all"/> Group TWO Selecct All</li>
            <li><input class="two_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 1</li>
            <li><input class="two_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 2</li>
            <li><input class="two_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 3</li>
            <li><input class="two_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 4</li>
            <li><input class="two_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 5</li>
            <li><input class="two_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check[]"> This is Item 6</li>
   </ul>     


        <script>
        $("#one_select_all").change(function(){
            $(".one_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });
        $("#two_select_all").change(function(){
            $(".two_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); 
        });
        $('.one_checkbox , .two_checkbox').change(function(){ 
            if(false == $(this).prop("checked")){ 
                $("#one_select_all").prop('checked', false);
            }else{
            $("#one_select_all").prop('checked', true);
            }
            if ($('.one_checkbox:checked, .two_checkbox:checked').length == $('.one_checkbox, .two_checkbox').length ){
                $("#one_select_all, #two_select_all").prop('checked', true);
            }else{
             $("#one_select_all, #two_select_all").prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: *Here the HTML goes...* Goes where?

Comment: I thought I will see the HTML after editing the code

Comment: looks like you accidentally posted the question before you finished typ...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant source code, thank you.

Comment: Its accidentally posted now its there please help..!!

Comment: please edit the question properly so that people can help you in solving your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rkamlekar/awnxx4zL/

Comment: well you added code but now it is unclear what you want to achieve and what you are struggling with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is a bit hard to understand and it makes it hard to help. It's also phrased in a very commanding manner. People here will help with code yo uare struggling with, not write code for you. You may want to review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. I suggest making use of `.is()` when you want to check if a item is checked or not.

Also, split up your work a little bit. Check one then two. Would not suggest you try to bank them together.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/awnxx4zL/2/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#one_select_all").change(function() { //"select all" change 
    $(".one_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
  });

  $("#two_select_all").change(function() { //"select all" change 
    $(".two_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
  });

  //".checkbox" change 
  $('.one_checkbox, .two_checkbox').change(function() {
    //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
    if (!$(this).is("checked") && $(this).hasClass("one_checkbox")) {
      //if this item is unchecked
      $("#one_select_all").prop('checked', false);
      //change "select all" checked status to false
    }
    if ($('.one_checkbox:checked').length == $('.one_checkbox').length) {
      $("#one_select_all").prop('checked', true);
    }
    if (!$(this).is("checked") && $(this).hasClass("two_checkbox")) {
      //if this item is unchecked
      $("#two_select_all").prop('checked', false);
      //change "select all" checked status to false
    }
    if ($('.two_checkbox:checked').length == $('.two_checkbox').length) {
      $("#two_select_all").prop('checked', true);
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks actually I am having three group checklist. Its working for me now.

Comment: @rkamlekar glad to hear it has helped. You may want to consider marking it as an answer.